# Read all the records in DynamoDB by a timely scan task

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

Say I have a DynamoDB with enough items that throws timeout exception when I do a scan using this basic Lambda function:

```js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});

exports.handler = function (event, context) {

    var tableName = "TABLE_NAEM";

    var params = {
        TableName : tableName,
        "ReturnConsumedCapacity": "TOTAL"
    };

    var counter = 1;

    dynamodb.scan(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            context.done('error', 'reading ddb failed: ' + err);
        }

        data.Items.forEach(function(element) {
            console.log(counter + "- " + element.whatever.S);
            counter++;
        })
    });

};
```

I want to do a scan for ALL items in the Table but I don't want to cause a Read Spike. Is there a way to run this Lambda function as a task, reading `N` items every `T` time until all the items are covered?

Comment: Some combination of Limit: N in your scan parameters plus managing pagination and then solve the problem of how to re-scan every T seconds, maybe using setTimeout/setInterval. You'll need to retain the LastEvaluatedKey from response K to populate ExclusiveStartKey in request K+1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are different approaches to solve this problem and I think I have tried them all. The solution which @cementblocks suggested works, but it's kinda overkill for such a small problem since you need to handle all the callback failures and if order matters to you it's not a reliable option.

I ended up importing my `DynamoDB` to `Redshift`. It is simple, reliable and once it's imported to `Redshift` you can do all the queries you want.

Here's [the related Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/RedshiftforDynamoDB.html) in AWS wiki page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an AWS Step Function to help manage your Lambda function.
The AWS Step Function can sleep between Lambda invocations. Your Lambda can return the LastEvaluatedKey and receive it as a parameter from the Step Function.